# React native TextInput

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm starting to learn react native, therefore I'm following the documentation, however, I can not test the TextInput, I copy past the example from the official documentation but nothing appears in my app.
I also remarked that when I add other components they doesn't appears also, however, when I remove the TextInput they appears as expected.
I searched online for some solution, I find a lot, but non works for me ( mostly the talked about the height of the component...).
also there is no error neither in the app nor in the debugger-gui
does anybody have a solution?
  
**Edit1**
to get started with react I followed the instructions and create AwsomeProject,
then in the app.js (I also tried to create a separte component and call it in app.js) I added this code :

```
   <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
    <TextInput style={{ backgroundColor: '#ededed', height: 60 }} value={'Hello'} />
  </View>
```

Comment: add some code also

Comment: Do you receive an error message with red background? If yes what is it showing?

Comment: @aName the code snippet you have should work as expected ... but with a **gray** background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know without a code example but are you importing TextInput at the top of the file?

```
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: it was as simple as that, also I named my component TextInput which create confusion for react, therefore, it doesn't show anything event an error message

Comment: Good to hear you got it sorted.  Usually the error message would be more descriptive like "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: TextInput"

Comment: yeah that what confused me, there was no feed back.

Answer (score 2):

I think by adding flex:1 and onChangeText in the textInput will solve the issue

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {View, TextInput,Button} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state={
    text:"Hello"
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red',flex:1,justifyContent:'center'}}>
          <TextInput style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 60,width:300 ,borderWidth:1,borderColor:"white"}} value={this.state.text} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}/>
          <Button
           title="Learn More"
           color="#841584"
           accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
          />
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code of the simplest use of a TextInput.

```
import * as React from 'react'; 
// We have to import the components that we are going to use in our app. 
// TextInput is a part of the 'react-native', which should be already installed if you have followed the official documentation correctly.
import {View, TextInput} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component { // Our main App component
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}> // The TextInput is in a view. This view has a red background. When you use the link below, you will see a red section at the top of the screen. That is our view.
        <TextInput style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 60 }} value={'Hello'} /> // This is the TextInput component, which has the text "Hello" in it. As you can see, it will be rendered in the parent red view.
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Check out the live example in this [link](https://snack.expo.io/@aktasfat/crabby-churros).

**More:**
[React Native Getting Started on TextInput](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput)

Let me know if it doesn't clarify what you're trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

To show text input on UI, You need to use flex concept or need to define width of text input.

or